# how to populate a textfield on load in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngroute, routeparams

I am developing an application where I want to load one text field in a form with it being disabled for editing. I want two things to be answered. Actually my idea is to fetch one mongodb`_id` from the url and pass it to my controller and fetch the corresponding Email id from db and populate it in the loading form so that the users cannot edit that in the field.

Question 1: I have written the api for fetching the email id using ID but I am not sure how to fetch the `_id` from my url.

say `www.xyzabc.com/register.html?id:57c5dda12e63d15d2e4dea2c`
`www.xyzabc.com/register.html?57c5dda12e63d15d2e4dea2c`

any format of url.

My api goes like this:

```
$scope.fetchEmail = function (id) {

    $scope.id = "57c5dda12e63d15d2e4dea2c";
    console.log("logging routeparam");
    console.log($scope.id);
    UserServices.fetchEmail($scope.id, function (email) {

        console.log("insied fetch fn");
        console.log(email);
        $scope.user.email = email;

    });
}
```

The above code does everything perfect if the id is hardcoded. I dont know how to get the url parameter from the url as id.

Question 2: Once I get my id in the `$scope.user.email = email;`  it should get populated in the field which is forbidden for the users to edit.

I tried the code below but it did not work for me.

```
<input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model={{"user.email"}} disabled="disabled" required>
```

Can anyone help me out in this concern.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use URL routing to pass variables in your angular urls. I believe you want a unique url for each id, right?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
            expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
        }
    })
```

Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#url-parameters

A simple format for your HTML would be the following.

```
<input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-disabled="true" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your url has parameters like `?id=57c5dda12e63d15d2e4dea2c` then you can use `$location.search(url)` which will return an object like `{'id':'57c5dda12e63d15d2e4dea2c'}` and then you can pass that to the api to fetch mail.